# I get this error whan launching my flutter application : "Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/me/carda/androidcore/0.7.2/androidcore-0.7.2.aar'. "

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I get the error below when launching my flutter application .

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A125F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: �l�ment inattendu (URI : "", local : "extension-level"). Les �l�ments attendus sont <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: �l�ment inattendu (URI : "", local : "base-extension"). Les �l�ments attendus sont <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Format incorrect du param�tre -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform androidcore-0.7.2.aar (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download androidcore-0.7.2.aar (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.2)
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/me/carda/androidcore/0.7.2/androidcore-0.7.2.aar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/me/carda/androidcore/0.7.2/androidcore-0.7.2.aar'. Received status code 521 from server: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
```

This is the result of flutter doctor on my machine .

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22621.963], locale fr-SN)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.6)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I just want to lauch my flutter application . The code was working perfectly the last time I opened it

Comment: There are several hints in the error message and Doctor's output. What did you try to resolve these issues? It seems like the problem is with your build environment.

Comment: It is looks like repository server is down.

Comment: That's what i think the repository server is down .

Comment: @Ber I tried to clean the cache and rebuild without succes . I also replace jcenter repository by mavenCentral and the problem persit.

Comment: On Twitter they said the server was up again yesterday

Comment: @Ber thank's very much it is working now it was the server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. I don't apply any fix it's just the server was down .
But now it is working perfectly Thank's @Ber